# How to force redisplay after you change truncate-lines?

Tags: redisplay

The boolean variable `truncate-lines` controls whether continuation lines are displayed or not. I use this when I am checking some log file where the very long lines are truncated thanks to a previous `(setq truncate-lines t)`. This is convenient since the relevant contents is usually at the beginning of the lines. However I sometimes need to see the end of the inspected lines and I'll occasionally toggle `truncate-lines` on and off (this is done in code temporarily bound to a function key).

The problem is that toggling `truncate-lines` on and off does not update the display unless I do some editing, or move the cursor far enough, or .. I don't know what. I tried to insert a `(redisplay t)` in my toggling code but this is not enough.

What bit of elisp magic will cause the display to be updated according to the new value of `truncate-lines` once it is changed?  And, by the way, is the lack of immediate update a bona fide bug?

*How to reproduce the problem:* After some investigation, it seems that the problem appears because I invoke the toggle via some key binding and not by `execute-extended-command` aka `M-x`. [Here is a test file for you to download](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~phs/test_file). Start with `emacs -Q test_file`, then `eval-defun` the first expression. Now `M-x ttl` does the toggle ok but on my machine hitting `CTRL l` (now bound to `ttl`) does the toggle **without redisplay**. If I move to end of buffer, the redisplay is activated.
FWIW I use emacs 24.5.1

*Added Jan. 5th:* it turns out that the behaviour described above is due to a minor bug that will be fixed in Emacs 25, [see here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-25&id=50575b1bdd7fcb4d1bf525fb5ca635fe7ab7d8c6). In principle there is nothing wrong with changing `truncate-lines` directly without going through `toggle-truncate-lines`.

Comment: Can you provide a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` to reproduce the problem? I `toggle-truncate-lines` a lot, and I don't recall it ever failing to have an immediate effect on the visual state of the buffer.

Comment: I've now just done that. Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out that the redisplay works ok when I toggle via `execute-extended-command` aka `M-x`. It fails when I toggle via key bindings.

Comment: You should use `toggle-truncate-lines` rather than changing directly the value of `truncate-lines`. `(global-set-key "\C-l" 'toggle-truncate-lines)` does work. [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html#Line-Truncation)

Comment: @JeanPierre: that's probably the answer.  Could you change your comment to an answer?

Comment: @JeanPierre: Yes, please do post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks JeanPierre. I did not know that a `toggle-truncate-lines` function already existed. This solves my problem. The code in `simple.el` is more involved than just a `setq` :-) It is really too bad that the documentation string for `truncate-lines` does not refer to the toggle function and recommend using it.

Comment: phs: You can `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest a documentation change.

Comment: @phils: good idea. I just did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the command `toggle-truncate-lines` rather than changing directly the value of variable`truncate-lines`.  This command does ensure the display is updated (apparently through `force-mode-line-update` although nor its name neither its docstring does suggest that).

It is described in emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html#Line-Truncation) but unfortunately not mentionned in `truncate-lines` docstring nor in the section about truncation of elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Truncation.html#Truncation).